# Is there a SQLAlchemy session.add_all() equivalent on GORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am new to Golang and I am trying to bulk update models for a table.

I have a "owners" table where I am trying to update multiple rows.
my go model (not complete):

```
type Owners struct {
    OwnerID      int64   `gorm:"primaryKey;not null"`
    OwnerName    string
    Eligibility  bool
}
```

I have a logic that updated the Eligibility to true or false for multiple rows

Using Python SQLAlchemy, I can create a session and use add_all() method to bulk update the rows.
Is there something similar on GORM.

I tried the following code

```
const batchSize = 100

func bulkUpdate(owners *[]Owners) {
    for i := 0; i < len(*owners); i += batchSize {
        end := i + batchSize
        if end > len(*owners) {
            end = len(*owners)
        }
        batch := (*owners)[i:end]
        log.Println("batch=", len(batch))
        //result := config.DB.Table("owners").Updates(batch)
        result := config.DB.Model(owners).Updates(batch)
        log.Println("result=", result)
        if result.Error != nil {
            log.Println(result.Error)
        }
    }
    config.DB.Commit()
}
```

But this gives me error "unsupported data"

I can do the following, which works fine:

```
for _, ownership := range owners {
    config.DB.Save(&ownership)
}
```

but since I have 4000+ rows, it takes lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still pretty new to Go and Gorm but I do not believe there is a similar function to the add.all() function in SQLAlchemy.

For GORM I believe you have to use the Create() method with a slice of structs as input which will insert multiple records in a single transaction.  Though that may not be exactly what you're looking for :).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I'll just add go routines and run them. I tried doing that for a smaller chunk and it seems to be improving the performance.